# Can you load the mmenu WordPress plugin so that the Javascript appears at the bottom of the page?

Tags: wordpress, mmenu

You can enqueue many scripts in WordPress so they don't stop page rendering by placing the Javascript at the bottom of the page (near ). Is this possible with the mmenu plugin? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will need to edit the plugin code but it's possible. You will need to use the `wp_enqueu_script` function and set parameter `$in_footer` to `true`.

Refer [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).